# add items to ListBox Control from ListView Control

Tags: c#

In my project I am trying to add the `SelectedItems` of `ListView` control (Only Items not sub items) to the `ListBox` Control. After adding, the selected Items of the `ListView` Control should get deleted. I am very close but I think I am doing something wrong in my code which leaving single selected item in the `ListView` control.

```
ListView --> lvEmpDetails
ListBox  --> lbxEmpName
```

I tried the below code:

```
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems.Count; intCount++)
{
     lbxEmpName.Items.Add(lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[intCount].Text);  
     lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[intCount].Remove();                  
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Try looping 'backwards', that is:
 `for (int intCount = vEmpDetails.SelectedItems.Count - 1; intCount >= 0; intCount--)`

Comment: Did you set the MultiSelect property for the ListView control?

Comment: @Maku yes its working :) . why so?

Comment: @Thinhbk the MultiSelect property is True (default).

Comment: If you remove an element from SelectedItems collection you also change lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems.Count value.
This would work too instead of the for loop:
`while (lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
lbxEmpName.Items.Add(lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[0].Text);
     lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
    }`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do another way:

```
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems.Count; intCount++)
{
     lbxEmpName.Items.Add(lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[intCount].Text);  
     lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[intCount].Remove();    
     //Every time remove item, reduce the index           
     intCount--;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't delete the items in the same loop you're iterating them. Add them to a list and delete them afterwards:

```
var itemsToRemove = new List<ListViewItem>();

for (int intCount = 0; intCount < lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems.Count; intCount++)
{
     lbxEmpName.Items.Add(lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[intCount].Text);  
     itemsToRemove.Add(lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems[intCount]);
}

foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
{
    item.Remove();                  
}
```

Comment: This approach I used to use usually before.

Comment: I think I am missing some namespace to include in my program for this to work.  It saying "The type or namespace name ListItem could not be found (are you missing some directive or an assemble reference?)"

Comment: Maybe I have a mistake with the class name. Look what SelectedItems has

Comment: lvEmpDetails.SelectedItems has all methods in intellisense. (Sorry, I dont understand what you  are saying I am in beginner stage of c#)