# Move selected items from one listbox to another in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to move selected items in list box1 to list box2, and vice versa. I have two buttons, `>>` and `<<`. When I select items in listbox1 and then click on `>>` the items should move from listbox1 to listbox2.

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox source, ListBox destination)
{
    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;
    foreach (var item in sourceItems)
    {
        destination.Items.Add(item);
    }
    while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveListBoxItems(listbox , lstActivity);
}
```

Comment: "button2_Click_1"  this is the problem.

Comment: delete button2 then create new other button.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your code works fine. i tested it.
your question is "I try to move **selected** item in list box1 to list box2."

i think your button2 has problem.delete button2 and the code below

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveListBoxItems(listbox , lstActivity);
}
```

then create other button and create click event.

full source:

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox source, ListBox destination)
{
    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;
    foreach (var item in sourceItems)
    {
        destination.Items.Add(item);
    }
    while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}

private void first2second_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveListBoxItems(FirstListbox, LastListbox);
}

private void second2first_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveListBoxItems(LastListbox, FirstListbox);
}
```

this code is work. if you want select more than one item change property 
    SelectionMode = MultiSimple;

Comment: there is an error: Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: use ref in case you need to pass by reference. i.e. private void MoveListBoxItems(ref ListBox source, ref ListBox destination)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void buttonMoveToListBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedValue);
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedValue);
    }
}

private void buttonMoveToListBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.SelectedValue);
        listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: ListBox doesn't contain defenition for Add!

Comment: listbox.Items.Add it was just a  typo

Comment: Give Exception!!!:( "Value can not be null" in Line that wrote : listbox.items.add(listbox.selectValue);

Answer (score 0):

There will be conflicts for every deleted row, so go with the below code:

**>>**

```
     for (int intCount = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1; intCount >= 0; intCount--) 
     {
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItems[intCount]);
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItems[intCount]);
     }
```

**<<**

```
     for (int intCount = ListBox2.SelectedItems.Count - 1; intCount >= 0; intCount--)
     {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.SelectedItems[intCount]);
        ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItems[intCount]);
     }
```

If the above one doesn't work then try this:

```
while (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
{ 
    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItems[0].Text);  
    ListBox1.SelectedItems[0].Remove(); 
}
```

For more type of answers you can go with this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13067331/1577396)

Comment: @nawfal Actually I like this better because it gives some understanding(to me atleast) anyhow the like i provided contains the way you explained :)

Comment: give Exception in ListBox.Item.Remove!!!it is:"Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @user1770370 check my edited answer. Try to understand it (I havent checked it)

Answer (score 0):

[Here Two ListBoxes. When i select the name from Left listbox and click ">>" Button the data move to Right ListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnNRl.png)

Code..
currentItemText = LeftListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            currentItemIndex = LeftListBox.SelectedIndex;

```
        RightListBox.Items.Add(currentItemText);
        if (myDataList != null)
        {
            myDataList.RemoveAt(currentItemIndex);
        }
        ApplyDataBinding();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this code:

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox poSource, ListBox poDestination)
{
    while (poSource.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        poDestination.Items.Add(poSource.SelectedItems[0]);
        poSource.Items.Remove(poSource.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // > arrow
            $('#SingleRightMove').click(function() {                    
                    $('#fromBox option:selected').remove().appendTo('#toBox');  
                    //$("#tobox option").attr("selected", false);        
                    $('#toBox').find("option").attr("selected", false); 

            });
            // < arrow
            $('#SingleLeftMove').click(function() {
                 $('#toBox option:selected').remove().appendTo('#fromBox');
                 $("#fromBox option").attr("selected", false);
            });
            // >> arrow
            $('#AllRightMove').click(function() {            
                 $('#fromBox option').remove().appendTo('#toBox');
                 $("#toBox option").attr("selected", false);
            });
            // << arrow
            $('#AllLeftMove').click(function() {           
                 $('#toBox option').remove().appendTo('#fromBox');
                 $("#fromBox option").attr("selected", false);
            });




        });



    </script>
```

Comment: Ummm... this is definitely not an answer to the question that was asked, here. The question is about C#/Winforms.

Answer (score -2):

Get the >> and << buttons created with 2 list boxes like listbox2 and 3 below...get ur items in list box 2 first by something like get-content or get-adcomputer etc..

```
$buttonMOVERight_Click={
    foreach ($Srv in $listbox2.selectedItems)
        {$selectedServers=$Srv}
    $listbox3.BeginUpdate()
    foreach($TSrv in $Srv)
        {$listbox3.Items.Add($TSrv);
        $listbox2.Items.Remove($TSrv);}                         
    $listbox3.EndUpdate()
}

$buttonMoveLeft_Click={
        #TODO: Place custom script here
        foreach ($Srvs in $listbox3.selectedItems)
        {$ServersinRt=$Srvs}
    $listbox2.BeginUpdate()
    foreach($rSRv in $Srvs)
        {$listbox2.Items.Add($rSRv);
        $listbox3.Items.Remove($Srvs);}
        $listbox2.EndUpdate()
}
```

Comment: This answer is not for Winforms.