# How to Add value in the list box from another list box in window Application

Tags: c#

I am doing a windows application in Visual Studio 2012 in that I have some list of names in a list box . Now I need to select those names and need to add in another list box by clicking a ADD button . And also I need to remove from the 2nd list box if I click the REMOVE button and the name must go back to the main list box again .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344387/move-selected-item-from-listbox-to-another-listbox-in-c-sharp-winform

Answer (score 0):

Use ListBox properties to get selected item(s)--

ListBox.SelectedItem

or Loop (if the ListBox selection mode is set for multiselect)

ListBox.SelectedItems

methods to remove items--

ListBox.Items.Remove(obj)

ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index)

methods to add items--

ListBox.Items.Add(obj)